# numeric fields are showing as string after ingestion in elastic through csv

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have ingested my csv data in elastic search through logstash, However i am not able to figure out why all the numeric fields are showing as string after ingestion.How to change the data type during upload.i am not able to use aggregation on the fields over kibana because of the same.

Kindly suggest what to do ?

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0tU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`mutate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert) to `convert` your field to another type

```
filter {

  ... other filters...

  mutate {
    convert => { "fieldname" => "integer" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply will give it a try. However could you please tell  me how can i change the type of the field after ingestion in elastic search.  How and what step need to be taken ?

Comment: You can't change a type in ES once the field has been created. You can, however, create your own mapping in which you tell ES the type to use for each field. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks val you save my life . I would like to change the type at the time of ingestion through logstash. However as i have already uploaded the data in ES so How to delete that data from elasticsearch ? what if i delete only index , would it mean my complete data will be deleted ?If no then How and  what component need to be deleted to remove complete data against an index?

Comment: You have to delete your index, indeed, and re-index your data.

Comment: i want to delete the existing data itself in ES as i have changes in my logstash configuration file and want to re-upload it.would deleting index  remove complete data ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/your_index`

Comment: attached is my logstash configuration file and unable to upload data through it.Earlier it was working fine. I have also done the configtest which says ok.Could you please have a look.

Comment: the `elasticsearch` output is commented out, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Its also not giving output on console

Comment: Try to rename your CSV file and modify your config accordingly. It must be a sincedb issue.